# How to disable the HTTP port totally inside WSO API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

What configuration will help to disable HTTP port totally from WSO- APIM (Only https port will be in running/listening state)
I tried by removing http from carbon configuration, but it just removing from WSO-Store-UI perspective.

Unchecking the HTTP while PUBLISHING the API, solved problem. But, from back-end perspective, the port is still in listening mode.
It will be better to have a configuration process, that will completely disable HTTP port.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 API Manager has two transports. Those are

1. Servlet transport to serve the UI - This listenes in 9763(http) and 9443(https).
2. Pass through transport to serve the api requests - This listens in 8280(http) and 8243(https).

By going through your question, what I understood was, you want to disable the pass through transport listening in the https port. If so, you can do it as follows.

1. Find the axis2.xml file in repository/conf/axis2 folder.
2. Go to the "Transport Listeners" section.
3. There you will find a transport receiver with name "http" which listens in port 8280.

   ```
   <transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
   <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
   <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
   <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
   <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
   <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
   <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
   ```
4. Comment it out properly and restart the server.

Comment: I dont think it will be a problem. Just do a round of testing and see whether APIM works as normal. If so, you can neglect that exception.